# Ускорение программы

Tags: python

Как можно ускорить программу для нахождение делителей?
Нужно найти делители очень больших чисел.

```
a = int(input())
b = 0
for i in range(1,a+1):
    if b > 10000:
        break
    elif a % i == 0:
        b +=1
        print(i)
print(b)
```

Comment: Не пробовали чуть-чуть поискать по этому сайту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно перебирать делители до корня из числа, при этом будет находиться два делителя один из которых до его корня, а другой после корня. За исключениям случая, когда число будет целым квадратом - тогда нужно будет еще его добавить.

```
import math
a = int(input())
b = 0
temp = math.isqrt(a)
if a == temp*temp: 
    b+=1
    print(temp)
for i in range(1,temp):
    if b > 10000:
         break
    elif a % i == 0:
       b +=2
       print(i)
       print int(a/i)
print(b)
```

Порядок вывода делителей естественно будет не исходным.

Comment: мне нужно найти 1 делитель числа, то есть например делители 
число 10
делители 1,2,5,10
программа у меня находит их, но числа большие и у меня уже перебирает 2 часа, число "2792599493716575"

Comment: У тебя в коде находит все делители числа. мой код тоже покажет все делители числа, но в другом порядке. Для 10 он покажет 1, 10, 2, 5. Но не 1,2,5,10.
Мой код перебрал все делители числа. Их 540 всего.
Вот её вывод https://pastebin.com/TN3wf6ss

Comment: понял, спасибо, не сразу понял

Comment: ... и я советую автору вопроса всё таки прочитать ссылку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227252/%d0%a1%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%8e-%d0%b2-100-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0-1-2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd - там обсуждаются вопросы фактиризации 100-значных чисел, что больше представленного в вопросе 16-значного числа

Answer (score 0):

Тема факторизации больших чисел много раз [обсуждалась](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227252).

Если быть кратким, то:

1. Перестать проверять делимость четных чисел и на четные делители - там и так всё ясно.
2. Воспользоваться [эффективными алгоритмами](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/factorization)
3. Питон - это интерпретируемый язык, и есть сомнения в том, что в задачах, связанных со скоростью и эффективностью вычислений, его имеет смысл применять.

Answer (score 0):

Ускорение в 2 раза:

```
for i in range(1,a//2+1):
```

Дальнейшее ускоренние: примени алгоритм поиска простых чисел.

- Решето Эратосфена
- Решето Сундарама
- Решето Аткина

А потом перебирай комбинации по 2 из простых чисел и рекурсивно для получившигося цисла комбинация с простым делителем.